# Using Yomu to extract information (heroku's deploy)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, heroku, shared-libraries

I am using the Yomu library (https://github.com/yomurb/yomu) to extract information from a PDF file. But when I deploy my application using Heroku, it doesn't work and I think it's because the yomu documentation asks for JRE.

Do you know how I can verify if my application deployed in Heroku is JRE complatible?

I would appreciate if you could explain me how the heroku environment works or if someone has already gone through this problem, could you tell me how you solved it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.